# Run hyperledger fabric samples enroll admin error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I try to run Hyperledger Fabric samples code from github(https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html).

After I start Docker and run ./startFabric.sh, then I try to run node enrollAdmin.js to invoke a certificate signing request, but I got the following error:

```html
➜  fabcar git:(2433afd) ✗ node enrollAdmin.js
 Store path:/Users/xiajun/.Trash/fabric-samples/fabcar/hfc-key-store
Successfully enrolled admin user "admin"
error: [Client.js]: Error: Missing parameter. Must have a username.
    at _setUserFromConfig (/Users/xiajun/.Trash/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1279:27)
    at Promise (/Users/xiajun/.Trash/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1431:11)
    at setUserContext (/Users/xiajun/.Trash/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1412:10)
    at promise.then.then.then.then (/Users/xiajun/.Trash/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1691:17)
Error: Failed to load key or certificate and save to local stores.
    at promise.then.then.then.then.then.catch (/Users/xiajun/.Trash/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1701:19)
Failed to enroll admin: Error: Failed to enroll admin
```

I cannot find the answer from the Internet. Can Anyone help me?

Comment: you have missing parameter can you update with code example. ?

Comment: I used V1.1 the latesr version

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. It is the version problem. I used V 1.1 . After I changed to use V1.0.6, this problem gone.

But I don't know why.